# Why can't a multidimensional array be allocated with one new call in C++?

Tags: c++, standards

In C++ you can easily allocate one dimensional array like this:

```
T *array=new T[N];
```

And you can delete it with one statement too:

```
delete[] array;
```

The compiler will know the magic how to deallocate the correct number of bytes.

But why can't you alloc 2-dimensional arrays like this?

```
T *array=new T[N,M];
```

Or even like this?

```
T *array=new T[N,M,L];
```

If you want a multidimensional you have to do it like this:

```
T **array=new T*[N];
for(int i=0;i<N;i++) array[i]=new T[M];
```

If you want a fast program that uses matrices (matrix operations, eigenvalue algorithms, etc...) you might want to utilize the cache too for top performance and this requires the data to be in the same place. Using `vector<vector<T> >` is the same situation. In C you can use variable length arrays on the stack, but you can't allocate them on the heap (and stack space is quite limited), you can do variable length arrays in C++ too, but they won't be present in C++0x.

The only workaround is quite hackish and error-phrone:

```
T *array=new T[N*M];
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
   for(int j=0;j<M;j++)
   {
       T[i*N+j]=...;
   }
```

Comment: If all but the first dimension of the multidimensional array are constant expressions, you can dynamically allocate a multidimensional array, e.g. `int(*x)[3] = new int[3][3];`.

Comment: Are you aware of `boost::multi_array`?

Comment: "data in the same place" doesn't make a lot of sense. The ordering of bytes can make a huge difference. Enumerating a column-first allocated matrix in a row-first manner might cause page misses which can make the operation much slower. The 'same place' is then defined through page sizes. For hardcore performance matters, it's a good idea to keep track of that yourself and not have the compiler do it. You can perform a single allocation and set the pointers into that single, continuous memory block. If you want something _simple_, use the suggested containers for that...

Comment: Note that the workaround you propose does not necessarily result in the array being contiguous in memory.

Comment: @Brian -- ??? Explain. Or link.

Comment: PigBen, a new allocation can be _anywhere_ in memory, but is guaranteed to be contiguous (let's not talk about mem virtualization). Thus, performing multiple allocs for a single logical object such as a matrix can result in a perf. hit.

Comment: @mnemosyn -- I was asking about the workaround.  "T *array=new T[N*M];"  It's a single allocation.  Brian said that it doesn't necessarily result in the array being contiguous.  I was asking him to explain that.

Comment: @PigBen: Sorry, I completely mis-read the post. Mea culpa. You're right: It's a single allocation and it is contiguous. That 'workaround' should be the fastest way to accomplish this I believe.

Comment: @Pigben: Sorry, I was misreading or looking at the wrong place or something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your workaround of doing `T *array=new T[N*M];` is the closest you can get to a true multi-dimensional array. Notice that to locate the elements in this array, you need the value of `M` (I believe your example is wrong, it should be `T[i*M+j]`) which is known only at run-time.

When you allocate a 2D array at compile-time, say `array[5][10]`, the value `10` is a constant, so the compiler simply generates code to compute `i*10+j`. But if you did `new T[N,M]`, the expression `i*M+j` depends on the value of `M` at the time the array was allocated. The compiler would need some way to store the value of `M` along with the actual array itself, and things are only going to get messy from here. I guess this is why they decided not to include such a feature in the language.

As for your workaround, you can always make it less "hackish" by writing a wrapper class that overloads `operator ()`, so that you could do something like `array(i, j) = ...`.

Comment: +1 for writing a wrapper class with appropriate operator overloading. This is what I did.

Comment: Oh, the () operator I forgot that I can overload it too. thx.

Answer (score 3):

Because multidimensional array is something different then array of arrays/pointers.

Answer (score 1):

use std::vector

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't a multidimensional array be allocated with one new call in C++?

Because when the ISO wrote the C++ language standard, they didn't decide to add that feature to the language.  I don't know why they decided not to.

If you don't like that, you can create helper functions to allocate/free multidimensional arrays, or you can switch to a language like C# or Java that does support easily allocating multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do, however, is allocate an object containing a two-dimensional array off the heap. I would just write a wrapper class for it.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this question last night, and this solution came to me.

```
T * raw = new T[N*M];
T ** array = new T*[N];

for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
    array[i] = raw + i * M;
```

Now "array" acts just like a contiguous static sized two dimensional array.  You just have to take care of deleting both the raw array, and the multi-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a [Boost::multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/multi_array/doc/index.html), from the library of the same name, which provides a simple interface to a multidimensional array.  It can be allocated in one line, and at a sufficiently high optimization level is usually as fast as a native array.

Here's some example code from the library's website:

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <cassert>

int 
main () {
  // Create a 3D array that is 3 x 4 x 2
  typedef boost::multi_array<double, 3> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type A(boost::extents[3][4][2]);

  // Assign values to the elements
  int values = 0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        A[i][j][k] = values++;

  // Verify values
  int verify = 0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
      for(index k = 0; k != 2; ++k)
        assert(A[i][j][k] == verify++);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the comma is an operator.

```
int a = (3, 5, 7, 9);
```

The program will evaluate 3, discard the result,
evaluate 5, discard the result,
evaluate 7, discard the result,
evaluate 9, and assign it to a.

Hence the syntax you are looking for can't be use,
and retain backward compatibility to c.

Comment: The comma operator has the lowest precedence of all the operators, so this is a syntax error.  You'd need to say `int a = (3, 5, 7, 9);`.

Comment: The same syntax is used for function calls. If that can work, why not for array subscripts?

Comment: @casablanca: Because function calls and array subscripts are different things, and the C++ designers chose not to allow it.

Comment: @Dave Hinton: Of course the question itself is about *why* the designers chose not to have such a feature.